# Silent install of the firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla, silent-installer

I am trying to install a firefox xpi silently through an msi installer. I am doing so by the following method:

Unzip my `xpi` in some temp dir and copy all the contents of that to the `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxx.default\extensions\<uniqueid-for-my-addon>`

I expected the addon to be available the next time my firefox opens, but I am not able to get it. Can someone tell me if there is more to be done for a silent install of firefox addons?

Kapil

Comment: To elaborate further, I have a firefox plugin which cannot work standalone - it works in conjunction with a windows app. So, I package my firefox plugin with the msi installer and ask for user's permission before I start the install. The problem I have now is that if I do not do a silent install, the behavior is very clumsy.

Any pointers on how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the name of the folder you are placing inside the extensions folder, it has to be called as the extension id (which is defined inside the install.rdf file).

Also note that this will not be a completely silent install, the addon install dialog will warn the user the next time Firefox is started with that profile that a new extension has been installed.

Comment: This is not the ideal way to do this as it may be removed in future versions.

Comment: sdwilish, then how should one go ahead with a silent install? Are you saying that we might not be able to install silently at all in the future versions? That would be bad!

Comment: That wouldn't be bad... that would be safe! After all, it stops some of the "silent installs" (like the one described in the question) and thereby stops potential malware, spyware, backdoors, and other nice things we don't want on our computers.

Comment: THIS IS VERY BAD! During our product intall, one of the step is to install firefox plug-in. And it can't be silent install now.  WHY the firefox guy at least leave some setting/pref to let the old way work?? ANy one know the detail of this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to add your add-on [via the windows registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry).